# Java - Skipping values in CSV file

Tags: java, arrays, csv, filereader

I'm trying to read the CSV file located here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/haberman/haberman.data

I want to skip the first two values, but I'm not quite sure how I would do this.

I also want to enter each line that is read into a two-dimensional array, but only the last two values which I actually want. Again, I'm not quite sure how I would do it, specifically how I would size the array based on the number of lines in the file, and then actually parsing the data into the array.

Here's my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Input file which needs to be parsed
    String fileToParse = "haberman.data";
    BufferedReader fileReader = null;

    //Delimiter used in CSV file
    final String DELIMITER = ",";
    try
    {
        String line = "";
        //Create the file reader
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToParse));

        //Read the file line by line
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
        //    
        //this is where I get stuck
        //
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally
    {
        try {
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is trickier to parse than you realize.

Do not write your own CSV parsing code, use a CSV library, such as OpenCSV or Commons CSV.  Then you can ignore whatever you want to.

Comment: I can't work out how to import the openCSV library, could you please shed some light on this?

Comment: That's a very different question that depends on the environment you're in.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I'm using the Eclipse IDE